# ReplayKit with broadcast extension receiving audio

Tags: ios, twilio, replaykit

I am using a replaykit broadcast extension to share an iOS devices screen over twilio. The problem is that I can't receive audio from the remote party. Is this possible? Or is the broadcaster one-way only?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The current object & auth models don't let several apps to publish Tracks under a single Participant, the 2.10.0 release now lets your extension connect (as a unique Participant) without subscribing to a Track.

If you want to have a more traditional video conference with screen sharing, my colleague and fellow Twilion [Chris Eagleston](https://github.com/ceaglest) suggests you connect one ReplayKit broadcast extension Participant to share the screen and another app Participant to publish the camera and microphone, and receive audio/video Tracks as mentioned in [this GitHub issue here](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-ios/issues/357).

You can try using the ReplayKit Twilio Video sample app [here](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-swift/tree/master/ReplayKitExample) too!

Comment: But it's correct that the screen-sharing extension can not receive audio while broadcasting?